# How to move image to bottom of linear layout

Tags: android

I have been having an issue trying to place an image at the bottom of a particular placeholder. I have tried including bottom for the gravity in both the linear layout and image view, tried setting margins and some other things but cannot seem to get my logo to appear bottom of the place holder.

Below is the code and underneath that is an example of what I am trying to do. First image is how it currently looks and second image is what I want:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the solutions but at the moment it is not working. I will post the whole XML as it maybe something that is causing a confliction: The logo is at the bottom linear layout tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_client"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.tecocraft.challenge_reward.widget.ButtonTextViewBold
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/splsh_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_challenge_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_175sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_click_effect"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_start_chal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:text="@string/new_challenge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Resume_challenge_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_175sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_click_effect"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_recycle" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="@string/resume_challenge"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why not use `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` has a height of 0 and weight of 1, I could be wrong but it tells me that it has a parent of `LinearLayout`. Could you post full XML layout please?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Why not `FrameLayout` since this one is the best in terms of performance? `Relative` is the worse :)

Comment: relative is best for moving object. it can be done by `LinearLayout` too but it does not provide flexibility as `Relative` Provide.

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan well if it was worse they did't developed it in first place ;). but yah FrameLayout is better

Comment: Note : I said in terms of performance ! And yes, it is the worse from all the above (Frame / Linear / Relative)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Relative layout for the better approach

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/login_fb"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/login_fb"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

just learn properties or attributes of `Relative layout`

these are the properties

```
android:layout_alignParentTop
android:layout_centerVertical
android:layout_below
android:layout_toRightOf
android:layout_centerHorizontal
android:layout_centerInParent
etc......
```

you can move anything inside relative layout by using `RelativeLayout`, `Linear layout` will not help as Relative will do and if want go more advance then learn `Constraint Layout`.

for more properties please [visit](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to add the following view before the Views you want to align to the bottom of the screen. The following piece of code should help.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This creates an empty view, filling the empty space and pushing the next views to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

As you have nested layout.. Use this code

you just need to change `centre_horizontally` to `bottom` in your `Imageview`
code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cdmasim"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## ************************************************************************

**Before Update:**

Add this line in `Linear Layout` to align your layout items to Bottom

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

As shown in Image Logo is centered Horizontally so you can add this line in your `ImageView` to keep it in center

```
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, It's not working and I am not sure if it's because it's in a nested linear layout, I will post whole xml

Comment: it is working actually. that's why i added image too

Comment: Yeah it's working in your example :) See update xml because when I try to do the same within my xml it doesn't work

Comment: Updated my answer, See now.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could utilize Relative Layout inside your Linear Layout. Make the Relative layout as Children of your Linear layout. Set both `match_parent` on its width and height. Put your image inside Relative Layout, and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the image props. It should fix your problems

Comment: this works, but it doesnt seem an optimal solution. Since relativelayout will cover entire screen. But thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    use this code:-

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```